# How do I gain access to the Text string in the HttpResponse?

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am clearly missing something here.  I use:

```
let response = Http.Request("http://something.com/api/blahblah")
```

to retrieve an HttpResponse, but how do I gain access to the sgtring returned with in the Body. For example if I wanted to do something like:

```
let info = response.Body.Text
```

I know I can get the string directly by using Http.RequestString, but is there a way to also get it using Http.Request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample from [HTTP Utilities](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/Http.html) page:

```
let logoUrl = "https://raw.github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/master/misc/logo.png"
match Http.Request(logoUrl).Body with
| Text text -> 
    printfn "Got text content: %s" text
| Binary bytes -> 
    printfn "Got %d bytes of binary content" bytes.Length
```

isn't it what you need?

Comment: how can I work with a response body as with a HtmlDocument?